# Drop to AutoCAD, different behaviors

Tags: windows, winapi, com, drag-and-drop, autocad

I'm struggling with a difference between drag-and-drop from Windows Shell -> AutoCAD and drag-and-drop from our app -> AutoCAD.

If one drops a dwg file from our app to AutoCAD => AutoCAD makes an "open" operation
If one drops a dwg file from Desktop (for instance) to AutoCAD => AutoCAD makes an "insert" operation.

In both cases the path to the dwg file is correctly retrieved, the file is correctly read. "insert" means appending the content of the dropped file to the current AutoCAD drawing. "open" means closing the current AutoCAD drawing and opening the dropped file.

We did implement IDropSource using CF_HDROP (and DROPFILES) format, which works in a drag-and-drop from our application to Desktop, for instance.

Does anybody have a hint ?

Thank you.

Comment: Which of both is the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call, use the `DROPEFFECT_LINK` flag instead of the `DROPEFFECT_COPY` flag for the `dwOKEffect` parameter.